# Redux toolkit - Refresh store after dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a problem with Redux and I hope that you'll be able to help me. So, I extract some store variables to use them inside my page:

```
const {
  selectedRows,
  searchCriteria: { name, type},
  cookies: { pageNumber, pageSize },
} = useSelector((store) => store.cookiesSearch);
```

After the selection of some rows from a table, I press a button and another page will be rendered conditionally over the one with the table of cookies, I will do some actions there, and then I want to refresh my store data, to populate the table again with fresh data, modified after action. At the onClick action of my button I have something like this:

```
onClick={() => {
  dispatch(changeCookies());
  // after this I want to refresh the cookies list from the table
  // the next dispatch have to change pageNumber to 1, pageSize to 10 and the cookies list to []
  dispatch(refreshCookiesList())
  // the problem is that here the dispatch will use the old pageNumber and pageSize. for example if before the onClick action I was at page 3 in the table, the new rendered cookies list will be affected and the getCookiesList action will bring me the cookies from the third page 
  dispatch(getCookiesList({ pageNumber, pageSize })) 
}}
```

I want, after the `changeCookies` action, the table to be refreshed and to start from page 1. Do you have any possible fixes for this? How can I refresh the store data?

Comment: The most trivial solution may be to do `dispatch(getCookiesList({ pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 10 }))`. Outside of this though you'll need to split the `getCookiesList` action dispatch into a separate scope or `useEffect` hook, or manually call `store.getState` in this `onClick` callback handler. What else updates the `state.cookiesSearch.cookies` state?

Comment: I can't do this: dispatch(getCookiesList({ pageNumber: 1, pageSize: 10 })) because on the table I have an infinite scroll that works dependent of the store variables pageNumber and pageSize, and if I dispatch using 1 and 10, ok, the first page will be displayed correctly, but the second one will be actually the 4th one. Can you please explain a little more about the usage of useEffect in this case?

Comment: I don't see how it'd be any different than if resetting `pageNumber` to 1 and `pageSize` to 10 like your comment says when dispatching `refreshCookiesList`. Can you clarify this part? As for the `useEffect` hook, basically you can't access enqueued state updates from the callback closure, i.e. `pageNumber` and `pageSize` are `const` and have the static value from the outer scope.  Using a `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependency allows you to issue the `getCookiesList` as a side-effect when the state has updated and the component rerendered with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

By defalt Redux is synchronous, so we add middleware to the store. There are two solutions thunk or redux-saga. I guess you are using redux-toolkit with thunks working out of the box. In `redux-toolkit` you have `createAsyncThunk` function that allows make async actions and dispatch them. Here you have access to `getState`, so you do not need to pass `{ pageNumber, pageSize }` from outside (from component), but you can grab it directly from store.

```js
export const getCookiesList = createAsyncThunk('cookiesSearch/getCookiesList', (_, { getState }) => {
 const const {
  selectedRows,
  searchCriteria: { name, type},
  cookies: { pageNumber, pageSize },
  } = getState().cookiesSearch 
// do stuff
})
```

Thunks are dispatched as sync functions, so you can await (and you even have to in this case if you want your data synced):

```js
onClick={async () => {
  await dispatch(changeCookies());
cookies list to []
  await dispatch(refreshCookiesList())
  dispatch(getCookiesList({ pageNumber, pageSize })) 
}}
```